# File header template by Android studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio

When making Activity or Fragment, the desired annotation format does not appear in the file header. I changed the format in Settings.

`Settings -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header`

But it did not get what I wanted. The format was applied when creating a normal class file. It was not time to create an activity or fragment. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: What if you create a new empty file? The templates are weirdly specific - you might be looking for a class. That's also a Java file though, so it might not work with Kotlin at all